# c++ vector of queues destruction

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, destructor

I'm trying do this to destroy the `Products`:

```
vector < queue <Product*> > freshDeposit = ...;
for(queue<Product*> q : freshDeposit){
    for (Product p : q) {
        delete p;
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work! Can you help me?
Thanks!!

Comment: `Product` is not the same type as `Product*`.

Comment: You can´t delete a `Product p` because it´s not a pointer.

Comment: Auch! how fast come down-vote with these type of questions... Even when they are valid.

Comment: You probably want `queue<Product*> &q : freshDeposit` (note the `&`) to avoid useless copies.

Answer (score 2):

If available, you should almost always prefer smart pointers over raw pointers.

```
vector<queue<unique_ptr<Product>>> freshDeposit = ...;
freshDeposit.clear();
```

Or if you want to retain the empty queues,

```
for(queue<unique_ptr<Product>> &q : freshDeposit) {
    q.clear();
}
```

If you really, really, want to maintain the data structure as is, but just release the `Product` objects, then you have to use `deque` instead of `queue` and call `reset()` on the pointers.

```
vector<deque<unique_ptr<Product>>> freshDeposit = ...;
for(deque<unique_ptr<Product>> &q : freshDeposit) {
    for(unique_ptr<Product> &p : q) {
        p.reset();
    }
}
```